# использование собственной аннотации

Tags: java, аннотации

Добрый день.
Есть класс A
Есть класс B extends A
Класс B помечен аннотацией @MyAnnotation
как в метода класс А получить значение аннотации повешенной на классе B, не прибегая к:

```
Class aClass = B.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();
```

ведь может быть много классов extends A, и что бы каждый из них не описывать.

Comment: А вы считаете это правильным? Родитель вообще мало что должен знать о наследниках. По-хорошоему вообще ничего... А вы пытаетесь ими что-то там манипулировать. Бред же

Comment: В предке есть метод, который вызывает сервис с параметром класса. Ранее писал в потомках super.init(класс потомка). Думал переделать это дело на аннотации